# Make queries for tpch (sybase ase)

Tags: database, sybase, benchmarking, sap-ase

Hi i´m testing the TPCH benchmark for sybase ASE 15.0 .When I try to use:

```
 qgen -s 1 > default1.sql
```

I get the following error

> Open failed for ./1.sql at qgen.c:170

How do I create the queries for sybase in the proper way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

qgen needs an enviroment variable called DSS_QUERY in my case I didn´t exported  it .

This parameter should be defined with the path to the queries directory that qgen uses to build the queries .

```
export DSS_QUERY=PATH_TO_QUERIES_FOLDER
```